# Laravel 9 How to add an email domain whitelist to registercontroller?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Alright so I'm trying to make it so when a user registers they have to use allowed emails like gmail.com, hotmail.com, etc...

But I tried this `regex:/(.*)gmail.com$/i'` and it worked but for only gmail.com. How do I make it so it also allows other emails that I have added in my config('email_whitelist') file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to whitelist specific email domains on signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466888/how-to-whitelist-specific-email-domains-on-signup)

Comment: `'regex:/(.*)@(gmail|hotmail|live)\.com/i'` should work for what you want, unless you want to pull it from an array and build it.

Comment: Indeed I want to pull it from an array. How is that possible? My method does not work.